# Backbone.js: fetch({add: true}), trigger change event?

Tags: backbone.js

I am wondering if there is any way to get the changed models when passing the `add: true` to `fetch`. It renders all the new models in the collection but I'd like to also know if there is any models that changed.

Is this possible?

I also considered the possibility of passing a different function as the success handler to `fetch`, a function that will re-render only certain portions of the view and not the entire view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual pattern is to have a view that renders your models. You then:

- subscribe in the collection's view to the collection's `add` event in order to append the views of the added models.
- let your models' views subscribe to the model's `change` to re-render.

If you still want to have only one view, you:
 - subscribe to the collection's `add` event in order to append to the view.
 - subscribe to the collection's `change` event and update parts of the view.

Comment: I decided to go with a collection view and model views. The question is not really the one you answered. I am aware of change events. I'll take an example: a team project management app, I load the views of the tasks and then you change the details of one task. Now, I want to keep the already rendered views updated (talking about the task name, in this case). If I fetch and pass add: true, only the new tasks will be shown, it also doesn't trigger a change event. Another way I think would work is to trigger an event in the success handler of the fetch that has as parameter silent: true

Comment: to trigger an event for each model and update using jQuery the task name, in my example. Thus, the already rendered views are also kept updated. What do you think?

Comment: After the fetch, the change event *will* trigger for the updated models. Why do you want to trigger another one? Maybe I have not understood correctly...

Comment: You didn't understand correctly. I want to call fetch({add: true}). Because I don't want all the views re-rendered. Calling it with add: true, doesn't trigger a change event. I will get the new models but the current models won't be updated.

Comment: so I want a way to get the new models and update the current ones without re-rendering everything

Comment: I see. Well in that case shouldn't you do a fetch() and manually filter?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? What would a manual filter look like?

Comment: the path I chose was to override the `parse` function. It updates the models and this triggers the change event even if I call `fetch({add: true})`, which by default wouldn't change the current (already fetched) models.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 0.9.10, you should use `{update:true}` instead of `{add:true}`. This will tell the collection to trigger a `change` event for each one of its models that has changed. (Note that the `change` event is triggered on **the collection** not the models)

If you want the collection to add and update models, but not remove them, you can accomplish this like so:

```
myCollection.fetch({update:true, remove:false});
```

[Here's the relevant section in the Backbone.js documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch).

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the "add" event and trigger a method that only updates a portion of the view. You have to explicitly bind a collections events in order to re-render your view. So in other words you control which parts of the view should be rendered. Can you not just alter the function where you are rendering you view based on the collection "change" event?

Each model has a method isNew(), and hasChanged(). You could loop through your collection to see which models have changed. If there is an easier and more proficient way to do this, I am all ears.

Maybe you can post some code so we can see exactly what you are doing?

Comment: the only problem is that when calling `fetch({add: true})` the current models are not updated. If I call `fetch` witout `add: true`, all the views would be re-rendered and I don't want it.

Comment: If I call `fetch` the `reset` event is triggered and I can't alter the function based on a `change` event

Comment: Could post some code with an example of the data in your collection and the data being fetched from the server.

Comment: the models are updated (without re-rendering all the views) if I call `fetch({silent: true})`, however this triggers no event. But! I could do it and pass a success handler and trigger the event

Comment: What happens when you bind to the "add" event? I am guessing it is not firing since you said the collection remains the same. Are you sure the data you are fetching from the server does not already exist in the collection or have conflicting Id's?

Comment: The `add` event is triggered, when using `fetch({add: true})`. Right! The new views are appended. But this is not the only thing I want. I also want to update the current views without re-rendering them entirely.